# Junk movement with steady 60fps on Web canvas

Tags: javascript, sprites, movement, performance, html-canvas

I'm new to building games on canvas, and I'm trying to create one. But I encountered a problem with sprite movements. My sprites move is smooth, but sometimes it starts to "jump". FPS is stable 60 frames per seconds.

Here is minimal implementation to play with: https://codepen.io/antonmedv/pen/ROjqXw

Code:

```js
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
        extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
            ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
            function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
        return extendStatics(d, b);
    };
    return function (d, b) {
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();
var Sprite = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Sprite(img, width, height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = img;
        this.image = image;
    }
    return Sprite;
}());
function drawSprite(c, sprite) {
    c.drawImage(sprite.image, -sprite.width / 2, -sprite.height / 2);
}
function vector(x, y) {
    return { x: x, y: y };
}
function copy(a) {
    return vector(a.x, a.y);
}
var nil = function () { return vector(0, 0); };
function divide(a, b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        return nil();
    }
    return vector(a.x / b, a.y / b);
}
function negative(a) {
    return vector(-a.x, -a.y);
}
function add() {
    var list = [];
    for (var _i = 0; _i < arguments.length; _i++) {
        list[_i] = arguments[_i];
    }
    var x = 0, y = 0;
    for (var _a = 0, list_1 = list; _a < list_1.length; _a++) {
        var v = list_1[_a];
        x += v.x;
        y += v.y;
    }
    return vector(x, y);
}
function multiply(a, x) {
    return vector(a.x * x, a.y * x);
}
function rad(grad) {
    return grad * Math.PI / 180;
}
function angel(a, b) {
    var x = Math.atan2(a.y, a.x) - Math.atan2(b.y, b.x);
    if (x > Math.PI) {
        x -= 2 * Math.PI;
    }
    else if (x <= -Math.PI) {
        x += 2 * Math.PI;
    }
    return x;
}
function norm(v) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(v.x, 2) + Math.pow(v.y, 2));
}
function dot(a, b) {
    return a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y;
}
function normalize(a) {
    return divide(a, norm(a));
}
var bodies = [];
var Body = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Body(sprite) {
        this.sprite = sprite;
        this.mass = 1;
        this.position = nil();
        this.velocity = nil();
        this.force = nil();
    }
    return Body;
}());
var Plane = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(Plane, _super);
    function Plane(sprite, forward, normal) {
        var _this = _super.call(this, sprite) || this;
        _this.forward = forward;
        _this.normal = normal;
        _this.angle = 0;
        _this.elevator = 0;
        _this.thrust = 0;
        return _this;
    }
    return Plane;
}(Body));
function render(c, width, height, dpr) {
    c.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    for (var _i = 0, bodies_1 = bodies; _i < bodies_1.length; _i++) {
        var body = bodies_1[_i];
        c.save();
        if (body.position.x < 0) {
            body.position.x = width / dpr;
        }
        if (body.position.x > width / dpr) {
            body.position.x = 0;
        }
        if (body.position.y > height / dpr) {
            body.position.y = 0;
        }
        if (body.position.y < 0) {
            body.position.y = height / dpr;
        }
        c.translate(body.position.x, body.position.y);
        c.rotate(body.angle);
        drawSprite(c, body.sprite);
        c.restore();
    }
}
function timestamp() {
    return window.performance && window.performance.now ? window.performance.now() : Date.now();
}
void function main() {
    var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
    var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
    function setupCanvas() {
        canvas.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px';
        canvas.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
        var dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        canvas.width = rect.width * dpr;
        canvas.height = rect.height * dpr;
        c.scale(dpr, dpr);
        return dpr;
    }
    var dpr = setupCanvas();
    var plane1 = createPlane();
    attachControls(plane1, {
        thrustLevers: { up: 'ArrowUp', down: 'ArrowDown' },
        elevator: { up: 'ArrowLeft', down: 'ArrowRight' },
        fire: 'Space',
    });
    bodies.push(plane1);
    var now, dt = 0, last = timestamp(), step = 1 / 60;
    function frame() {
        now = timestamp();
        dt = dt + Math.min(1, (now - last) / 1000);
        while (dt > step) {
            dt = dt - step;
            simulation(step * 4);
        }
        render(c, canvas.width, canvas.height, dpr);
        last = now;
        requestAnimationFrame(frame);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(frame);
}();
function simulation(dt) {
    for (var _i = 0, bodies_2 = bodies; _i < bodies_2.length; _i++) {
        var body = bodies_2[_i];
        if (body instanceof Plane) {
            computeForceOnPlane(body, dt);
        }
        var acceleration = divide(body.force, body.mass);
        body.velocity.x += acceleration.x * dt;
        body.velocity.y += acceleration.y * dt;
        body.position.x += body.velocity.x * dt;
        body.position.y += body.velocity.y * dt;
    }
}
function computeForceOnPlane(plane, dt) {
    plane.forward = vector(Math.sin(-plane.angle - Math.PI / 2), Math.cos(-plane.angle - Math.PI / 2));
    plane.normal = vector(Math.sin(-plane.angle + Math.PI), Math.cos(-plane.angle + Math.PI));
    var c = 1 - norm(plane.velocity) / (100 * 1.5);
    plane.angle += c * plane.elevator * dt;
    var v = norm(plane.velocity);
    var a = angel(plane.forward, plane.velocity);
    var gravity = vector(0, plane.mass * 9.81);
    var thrust = multiply(plane.forward, plane.thrust * 0.9);
    var lift = multiply(plane.normal, v * trim(a, rad(50)));
    var drag = multiply(normalize(negative(plane.velocity)), Math.pow(2, (v - 100)));
    plane.force = add(gravity, thrust, lift, drag);
}
function trim(a, max) {
    if (a < max && a > -max) {
        return a;
    }
    return 0;
}
function createPlane() {
    var plane = new Plane(createPlaneSprite(), vector(-1, 0), vector(0, -1));
    plane.position = vector(100, 100);
    plane.thrust = 10;
    plane.radius = 20;
    return plane;
}
function attachControls(plane, controls) {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
        switch (event.code) {
            case controls.thrustLevers.up:
                plane.thrust += 5;
                if (plane.thrust > 10) {
                    plane.thrust = 10;
                }
                break;
            case controls.thrustLevers.down:
                plane.thrust -= 5;
                if (plane.thrust < 0) {
                    plane.thrust = 0;
                }
                break;
            case controls.elevator.up:
                plane.elevator = -1;
                break;
            case controls.elevator.down:
                plane.elevator = 1;
                break;
            case controls.fire:
                fire(world, plane);
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    }, true);
    document.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
        switch (event.code) {
            case controls.elevator.up:
            case controls.elevator.down:
                plane.elevator = 0;
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    }, true);
}
function createPlaneSprite() {
    return new Sprite('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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', 40, 30);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #9be2fe;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Movements usually look smooth, but sometimes they are really junky.

Here are the things I'm using:

- `clearRect`
- `requestAnimationFrame`
- time delta with `performance.now`
- constant time steps for physics simulation

I profiled it, but everything looks smooth in the report (60 fps, each frame has little Javascript, low CPU).  Also tried using round x,y for `drawImage`, still junk movements. If turn off all physics and set `const acceleration = vector(-1, 0)` sprite movements again jumps from time to time.

How do I make the movements consistently smooth?

Comment: RequestAnimationFrame passes a similar value to performance.now to the called function, why not use that?

Comment: Please include in the question itself a minimal complete verifiable example of the problem. Code on an external site can change or become unavailable, making the question less useful for future visitors.